# How to use Firebase on Symfony?

Tags: php, android, symfony, firebase

I want to use Firebase on my Symfony application, but I don't know which bundle I should use, can you please give me some suggestions?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: flagged as off-topic question.

Comment: The question can be relevant if you want Firebase like behavior in Symfony

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use firebase PHP client https://github.com/ktamas77/firebase-php. It is based on firebase REST API and allows you to interact with firebase realtime database.

Edit:
You can also have a look at: https://github.com/kreait/firebase-php

Answer (score 5):

Download this bundle first:
https://github.com/kreait/firebase-bundle

Then in your config file use the below configuration:

```
 kreait_firebase:
    connections:
      main:
        host: testpro-aee33.firebaseio.com
        secret: Qfqagapp07ZnjFeiZ9GtgsssdF477sdsdL44Ll5g
        references:
          users: users #tablename in the firebase database
```

Then in your controller,use like below:

```
$firebase = $this->container->get('kreait_firebase.connection.main');
$users = $this->container->get('kreait_firebase.reference.users');

$users->push([
    'emai' => 'test@demo.com',
    'id' => '121',
    'name' => 'Dummyname'
]);

$reference = $firebase->getReference('/users');
$userData = $reference->getData();
```